# Order of growth of a recurrence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following recurrence condition for $t \geq 2$

$$x_t = c_1\left(-\frac{1}{x_{t-1}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{x_{t-1}^2} + c_2}\right)$$

Let $x_1 = c_3$. Now, i would like to obtain the growth of the sequence $x_t$ or in simple terms whats the convergence rate , also $c_1,c_2,c_3 > 0$ are constants.

Comment: I don't think you defined $c_3$

Comment: In my problem it is just $2c_1$ but i dont think its required, that's why i have set $x_1 = c_3 > 0$

Comment: It might help to rewrite in terms of $y_t=1/x_t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence rate is defined as

$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|x_t-L\right|}{\left|x_{t-1}-L\right|}
$$

If the sequence converges to $0$, $L=0$. I do not believe this is the case in general, but for some combination of constants, this is true.  Maybe this will lead you to a way of a general proof.  Notice that

$$
x_t=c_1\left(-\frac{1}{x_{t-1}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_{t-1}^2}+c_2}\right)=\frac{c_1c_2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x_{t-1}^2}+c_2}+\frac{1}{x_{t-1}}}
$$

So, divide by $x_{t-1}$ to get

$$
\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}}=\frac{c_1c_2}{\sqrt{1+c_2x_{t-1}^2}+1}
$$

The limit as $t\rightarrow\infty$ is $\frac{c_1c_2}{2}$.  At the very least, we know that the convergence rate cannot exceed $\frac{c_1c_2}{2}$

Comment: is there any way we can write $x_t$ in terms of $t$ like for instance $x_t = O(1/t^{p})$ for some $p >0$

Comment: Not sure, but you will need to know what $L$ is first for a combination of constants before you can get the convergence rate.

Comment: In my case $c_1c_2 = 2$